# Почему не удается получить access_token VK.API с рабочего ПК?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Решил поизучать VK.API в свободное время.
Написал простой код для тестирования дома, все работает.

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result);
}

if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $urlCode = "http://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id={$clientId}&display=page&redirect_uri={$redirectUrl}&scope=offline&response_type=code&v=5.52";
    redirect($urlCode);
} else {
    $code = trim($_GET['code']);
    $urlToken = "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id={$clientId}&client_secret={$clientSecret}&code={$code}&redirect_uri={$redirectUrl}";
    $content = file_get_contents_curl($urlToken);

    print_r($content);
}
```

На работе не прёт: код виснет где получаю $urlToken.
Если вставить $urlToken в браузер, то токен приходит.
Доступ инет, кстати, через прокси.

С чем может быть это связано?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все, понял. Оказывается надо было дописать в функции file_get_contents_curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxyUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxyPort);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "user:password");
```